# In the process of oogenesis, when the egg completes meiosis 2, what actually happens?

Tags: homework, sexual-reproduction

oogenesis is the process of egg formation in females. 
**The process of formation of the ovum is as follows**

1. oogonium
2. primary oocyte
3. secondary oocyte
4. ovum

Comment: The meaning of question is not clear to me. "oogenesis is the process of egg formation in femalesformation of the ovum The process is as follows". If you are asking "formation of the ovum The process is as follows" then none of your options is a "process". All the options are either a structure or a stage.

Comment: Welcome to biology SE. Please take helps from [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour), [help centre](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help), [ask](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [don't ask](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [formatting](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). Before asking homework questions, visit the [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework)

Comment: Inside oogenesis it wouldn't be sperm. It would be ovum.

Answer (score 1):

Though the original question is terribly unclear;  seemingly the question wanted to  mean "what should be the correct time-order of the following structures in the process of [oogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oogenesis) in human?".

[image: Figure from Clegg and MacKean]
Fig-Human oogenesis.  Source: `*`

[Oogonium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oogonium#In_the_mammalian_fetus)(in [zoology](http://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Oogonium)), is a diploid cell (female gametogonium), that gradually gives rise to primary [oocyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oocyte)

In case of human oogenesis, this primary oocyte (diploid) get divided into 2 cells through [meiosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis)-1 ... a (1) secondary oocyte and a (2) first-[polar-body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_body).

(In human) After that, meiosis-2 take place; where the secondary oocyte give rise to 2 haploid cell: an (1) Ovum and a (2) secondary polar body. In other hand; the first polar body also due to meiosis-2 division, gives 2 haploid cells (both are secondary polar body).

So the order would be

Oogonium(1)-->Primary oocyte (2)--> secondary oocyte (3)--> ovum (4) if they meant the temporal order of these structures.

Reference:

> 1: `*` Advanced BIOLOGY: Principles and Application; by C.J. Clegg and D.G. MacKean; John Murray publishing; copyright 1994.